# How to map a domain name to node.js http server on Windows 2008/IIS 7?

Tags: iis, iis-7, node.js, windows-server-2008

I can't find any article which explains this. Someone does know ? thanks.

Problem is my domain is already mapped to IIS 7 through port 80. I want to map to same domain but to another port how would you do so ?

Comment: 1) DNS, it's not different than mapping a domain to any server. 2) Node is so poorly supported on windows, I think you need to rethink your strategy.

Comment: it works on Windows since you say it's no different than mapping any domain I will stick to windows it's not for production it's just for learning :)

Comment: Problem is my domain is already mapped to IIS 7 through port 80. I want to map to same domain but to another port how would you do so ?

Comment: You're going to need a proxy of some sort.  I don't believe IIS can do this, but you can write a simple asp 404 catch-all page that does it by opening an http request to `127.0.0.1:other-port/page/requested` and echoing the result.

Comment: @user310291, if it is just for playing around, why bother with this.  I have never hat a problem doing `localhost:8080` or whatever port I was running the dev server on.

Comment: I Want to show it to people also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see http://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/archive/2008/07/09/application-request-routing-arr-as-a-reverse-proxy.aspx

which requires you to download: http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting

---

Basically you create a "re-write rule" using a IIS Extension called "Application Request Routing"

Comment: thanks for suggestion though not sure I will be capable of understanding I'm total nuts at networking stuff :)